# Convert or parse datetime coming from external system and save it in salesforce

Tags: apex, json, callout, datetime, parser

I am calling a rest api and one of the attribute of the response is datetime which is in CST format(6/26/2023 7:01:50 AM). I tried converting to date time format but its throwing Invalid date/time: 6/26/2023 7:01:50 AM error .
Which is the best way to convert/parse to salesforce supported datetime and also preserves the datetime value coming from external system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Determine the Timezone Offset:** Since CST (Central Standard Time) does not specify whether it's Central Standard Time in the USA or China (they have different offsets), you need to know the specific offset. Assuming it's Central Standard Time in the USA (UTC-6), you'll need to adjust for this offset

**2. Convert to Datetime in Apex:** to convert the datetime string to a Salesforce-supported datetime format. You can use the Datetime.newInstanceGmt(year, month, day, hour, minute, second) method to create a datetime object in GMT (UTC) and then adjust it for the CST offset.

**Here i written sample Snippet:**

```
String cstDatetimeString = '6/26/2023 7:01:50 AM'; // Replace this with your datetime string
 Datetime cstDatetime;
    
    try {
        // Split the input string into its components
        List<String> datetimeParts = cstDatetimeString.split(' ');
        List<String> dateParts = datetimeParts[0].split('/');
        List<String> timeParts = datetimeParts[1].split(':');
        
        Integer year = Integer.valueOf(dateParts[2]);
        Integer month = Integer.valueOf(dateParts[0]);
        Integer day = Integer.valueOf(dateParts[1]);
        Integer hour = Integer.valueOf(timeParts[0]);
        Integer minute = Integer.valueOf(timeParts[1]);
        Integer second = Integer.valueOf(timeParts[2]);
        
        // Assuming CST is UTC-6
        Integer cstOffset = -6; // CST offset in hours
        Datetime gmtDatetime = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
        gmtDatetime = gmtDatetime.addHours(cstOffset); // Adjust for CST offset
        
        // Now, gmtDatetime contains the Salesforce-supported datetime in GMT (UTC)
        System.debug(gmtDatetime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle parsing errors
        System.debug('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sahil,
Thanks for your inputs.
Well I am getting error in this line
cstDatetime = Datetime.parse('M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a', cstDatetimeString);

Error is : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void parse(String, String) from the type Datetime

Comment: Sorry for that i am updating the code snippet check it out.